# subsetting rows where values "turn off and on"

Tags: r, filter, subset, tidyverse

I have a dataset about countries policy responses to Coronavirus, and i am plotting each countries responses as labels with geom_text. I have created an example dataset of what one policies values might look like for one country. If the policies value is 0, then there is no active policy. The policy is active if it ranges from 1-5 and the scale of the policy increases as it gets larger.

So the problem i had was i wanted to subset all the start and end dates of the policies so i could later plot them as labels. I managed to accomplish this using a column with lagged values and one with lead values. Using these, i was able to detect when a policy "turned on" by checking if the previous value was any value other than the policy value. I did the same for the policy end but with the lead value this time.

My question is simply that i wanted to know if anyone knew of a more efficient way of doing this, Thank you.

Edit: Changed some variable names and added in the output for the label policy start/end variables.

```r
library(tidyverse)


# 0 represents no policy being active
# the values 1-5 represent a growing scale of the policy 
num <- c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4), rep(0,8), rep(3, 4), rep(0, 5), rep(2, 4), rep(0, 2))
num
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0

# simple dates 
date <- seq(as.Date("2020/09/01"), by = "day", length.out = length(num))

# making the dataframe 
df <- data.frame(date, num)

#creating a lag to try to help filter out when policies started and ended 
df <- df %>%
  mutate(lag = lag(num), # lag for previous value 
         lead = lead(num)) # lead for next value 

# filtering when the policies "turn on" 
policy_start <- df %>%
  filter(num == 1 & lag %in% c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5) | 
         num == 2 & lag %in% c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5) |
         num == 3 & lag %in% c(0, 1, 2, 4, 5) |
         num == 4 & lag %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5) |
         num == 5 & lag %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

policy_start
#>         date num lag lead
#> 1 2020-09-06   1   0    1
#> 2 2020-09-11   2   1    2
#> 3 2020-09-23   3   0    3
#> 4 2020-10-02   2   0    2

# filtering when the policies "turn off" 

policy_end <- df %>%
  filter(num == 1 & lead %in% c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5) | 
         num == 2 & lead %in% c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5) |
         num == 3 & lead %in% c(0, 1, 2, 4, 5) |
         num == 4 & lead %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5) |
         num == 5 & lead %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

policy_end
#>         date num lag lead
#> 1 2020-09-10   1   1    2
#> 2 2020-09-14   2   2    0
#> 3 2020-09-26   3   3    0
#> 4 2020-10-05   2   2    0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the dataframe without lagged values and lead values.

```
#subsetting the rows
policy <- c()
for(i in 1:length(df$num)){
     policy[i] <- case_when(df$num[i]>0 & df$num[i]!=df$num[i-1] ~ "start",
df$num[i]>0 & df$num[i]!=df$num[i+1] ~ "end")
    }
#Creating a dataframe with a column with "start" and "end" of policies
df <- cbind(df,policy)
df
#>         date num policy
#>1  2020-09-01   0   <NA>
#>2  2020-09-02   0   <NA>
#>3  2020-09-03   0   <NA>
#>4  2020-09-04   0   <NA>
#>5  2020-09-05   0   <NA>
#>6  2020-09-06   1  start
#>7  2020-09-07   1   <NA>
#>8  2020-09-08   1   <NA>
#>9  2020-09-09   1   <NA>
#>10 2020-09-10   1    end
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for.